# Get Distance Between Point and Side of Ellipse

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

So I have an ellipse where I know the two foci, the length and the width and all the relevant information. I then have a point somewhere in the ellipse. This point is known and an arbitrary angle ($\theta$) is known. I want to find the distance between the point in the ellipse and the side of the ellipse at the point along the angle. In the picture below is an example.

[image: diagram]

I want to find the distance between the $(1,-1)$ point and the $(x,y)$ point which is unknown. I'm not sure how to even begin this. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you write the equation of the ellipse? Can you write the equation of the line at angle $\theta$ through $(1,-1)$? Can you solve these as two simultaneous equations in two unknowns?

Answer (score 2):

The equation of your ellipse is: $\frac{x^2}{6^2}+\frac{y^2}{10^2}=1$. 
Also from your picture, the pt at distance r away from (1,-1) is $(1+r\cos \theta, -1-r\sin \theta)$.  Now you can solve $\frac{(1+r\cos \theta)^2}{6^2}+\frac{(-1-r\sin \theta)^2}{10^2}=1$ for r. 
I get a quadratic equation in r: $ar^2+br+c=0$, where the coeff's a,b,c may depend on $\theta$.

Comment: It's not a circle. It has two focus points. If it were a circle the foci would be at the center and the eccentricity would be 0

Comment: Since the foci are on the y-axis, and $(\pm 10,0),(0,\pm10)$ are pts, it must be a circle.

Comment: Oops. I made that and didn't even notice my mistake. Updated the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the new info, I have updated my answer also